# Site not reachable after moving the NS server from Godaddy to Route53

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-route53

As per my title, I want to use the NS server from Route53.
I've exported the zone files from Godaddy, imported in Route53
and then I've added the NS record from Route53 to Godaddy.
Since then, the website is unreachable.
Now I reverted back the old NS and everything is came back to normal.
As extra piece of information, I left one of the NS from route53 in the DNS of godaddy and used a dns checker and I got this.

> Superfluous name server listed at parent: ns-1412.awsdns-48.org
>
> A name server listed at the parent, but not at the child, was found. This is most likely an administrative error. You should update the parent to match the name servers at the child as soon as possible.

Comment: Rather than adding NS records, you should be changing the nameservers at the registrar level (which may be GoDaddy, but in a different place).

Comment: you should give the name involved if you want to get help and since you are paying Route53 did you ask their customer service?